# Loading Managed Object Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

There are two entities in my app **Folder** & **List**. The first view controller is a table view with a list of Folder entities. When tapping on a table view cell I segue to another table view displaying all the List(s) (ordered set) of that folder. I pass the reference to the second view controller when segueing from the table view cell.

```
  let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ListViewController
  let indexPath = UITable.indexPathForSelectedRow()
  let selectedList = folders[indexPath!.row]
  destinationVC.selectedFolder"
```

However In my second view controller I am not using a fetch request but the reference to the folder. I have a function to load the data into an array, which I use to populate the tableview.

```
var folderListArray = [List]()

func loadData() {

    var unsortedList = NSMutableArray()
    for singleItem in selectedFolder.list {
        let loopNote = singleItem as! List
        unsortedList.addObject(loopNote)
    }
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    guestlistArray = unsortedList.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor]) as! [list]

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

I use the function `loadData` in viewWillAppear & viewDidAppear. But when I add to the list with a modal then dismiss the modal the table view does not reload the data. It is saving correctly, I just have to go back to the previous view controller and segue again to see the added items.

Why is this ? And what is the best method to keeping this type of managed object data in sync ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` does not get called after dismissing a modal. If the segue is changed to a push segue then `viewDidLoad` gets called after adding items to the **tableview** then you can reload the table data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you

1. Assign the new `List` to the correct `Folder`.
2. Save the context.

Then your reload method should work.

Also, set a breakpoint to check if your methods are called. If not, consider implementing a delegate which is a standard pattern for detail controllers handling editing or adding to data.

Finally, consider simplifying the sorting code. You are essentially making two copies of the data, which is really not necessary. I would recommend you add a function to your `Folder` class to return a sorted list. This can be a one-liner using the API `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` of `NSSet`.

Comment: Sorry just made an edit. The Lists are saving and adding to the Folder, I just have to go back to the previous view controller and segue again. I will try out  your other suggestions.